# Find a part of a string using python?

Tags: python

For example:

```
string = "abcdefghi"
separated = "abc" + x + "ghi"
x = ???
```

I want to find x, using any string.

Comment: `x=re.search('(?<=abc).*(?=ghi)','abcdefghi').group(0)`

Comment: @bulbus - do you really think posting a regex expression, as a comment, with no explanation, is helpful to someone asking such a question?

Comment: or some poor lost soul unaware of the `re` module arriving here via google search

Comment: @DavidMakogon apologize! posted as answer. Wanted to test whether the user finds it useful or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x=re.search('(?<=abc).*(?=ghi)','abcdefghi').group(0)
print(x)
```

**output**

```
def
```

**Explanation**
Regex

```
(?<=abc)  #Positive look behind. Start match after abc
.*        #Collect everything that matches the look behind and look ahead conditions
(?=ghi)   #Positive look ahead. Match only chars that come before ghi
```

`re.search` documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search).
A `Match Object` is returned by `re.search`. A `group(0)`  call on it would return the full match. Detail  on `Match Object` can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects).

**Note:**
The regex is aggressive so would match/return `defghixyz` in `abcdefghixyzghi`.
See demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/KuQeBY/1).